# My handleClick event is not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, components

The functionality of the handleClick is to simply do `this.setState({details: true})` and vice-versa when it is already true. The console log shows that the state of details is changing between true and false on every click however the line only shows "Couldnt call the details"

```
          const retval = (
            <div>
              <hr />
              <div  className="weather-card">
                <h3>City: {this.state.city}</h3> <img onClick={() => this.handleClick()} src={this.state.image} />
                <h3>
                  Temprature: {this.state.temp} Feels Like: {this.state.feels}
                </h3>
                <p>{this.state.w_status}</p>
                <p>{this.state.description}</p>
                <div id="details" className="weather-details">
                  {this.state.details ? "well well well": "Couldnt call the details"}
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
```

```
  async handleClick(e) {

    if(this.state.details == true){
        this.setState({ details: false});
        console.log("It is hidden");
    }
    else{
        this.setState({ details: true});
        console.log("It is shown");

    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.setState(prev => ({details: !prev.details}))` try this and remove that if else

Answer (score 1):

Would you please post the entire code since besides refactoring to optimize a bit I don't see why it doesn't work.

Optimization:

```
//before return
const { details, city, temp, feels, image } = this.state
// after return
onClick={() => this.setState({ details: !details })
```